# Dynamic LinearLayout inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with Cards that looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_acts_list_item_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Header text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <!--My dropdown Button -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:gravity="center">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_collapse_act" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Contains items that are visible without expanding -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_acts_list_visible_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            />

        <!-- Contains items that are visible after expanding -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_acts_list_expandable_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And I've got two maps from API: first contains elements to be shown on screen for all time(must be added to **fragment_acts_list_visible_layout** in code above), other with elements that must be shown while user clicks expand button (**button** in code above, must be added to **fragment_acts_list_expandable_layout** in code above).

I want to represent each map entry of both maps with layout above:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/act_row_field_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/act_row_field_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to do this the right way?

Using a code such as `viewHolder.visibleLayout.addView(row);` in `onBindViewHolder` method gives me duplicated visible elements and wrong expandable layout height just because that's how RecyclerView `onBindViewHolder` works(called multiple times, adding my row each time called).

**UPD: this is my bindViewHolder method:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                             int i) {
    viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    Act act = acts.get(i);
    ActToDisplay visibleSettings = formatActFields(act, viewSettings);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : visibleSettings.getVisibleFields().entrySet()) {
        LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.act_row, viewHolder.visibleLayout, false);
        TextView fieldName = row.findViewById(R.id.act_row_field_name);
        TextView fieldValue = row.findViewById(R.id.act_row_field_value);
        fieldName.setText(entry.getKey());
        fieldValue.setText(entry.getValue());
        viewHolder.visibleLayout.addView(row);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : visibleSettings.getInvisibleFields()
            .entrySet()) {
        LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.act_row, viewHolder.expandableLayout, false);
        TextView fieldName = row.findViewById(R.id.act_row_field_name);
        TextView fieldValue = row.findViewById(R.id.act_row_field_value);
        fieldName.setText(entry.getKey());
        fieldValue.setText(entry.getValue());
        viewHolder.expandableLayout.addView(row);
    }

    //check if view is expanded
    final boolean isExpanded = expandState.get(i);
    viewHolder.expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpanded ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    viewHolder.buttonLayout.setRotation(expandState.get(i) ? 180f : 0f);
    viewHolder.buttonLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> onClickButton(viewHolder.expandableLayout, viewHolder.buttonLayout, i));
}
```

**UPD2:**
Solved by adding `.removeAllViews() in both visible and invisible layouts in`onViewRecycled` method, but the second problem is not gone - expandable layout height is way too big.

This is the screen from emulator that must show 1 visible element and additional one after clicking expand. Why this card is that big(seems like it counts wrap_content wrong)?
[image]

**UPD3:**
Problem with expandable layout height was my mistake - i've set expandable layout orientation to horizontal instead of vertical

Thanks to @AbuYousuf and @pskink

Comment: when user click on expend then fragment_acts_list_visible_layout will be hide or show.

Comment: @AndroidTeam fragment_acts_list_visible_layout must be shown for all time, clicking on expand button must only enlarge whole cardview to show fragment_acts_list_expandable_layout below visible items

Comment: post your `onBindViewHolder` method

Comment: @AbuYousuf added

Comment: its because you have to remove all the child views from `visibleLayout` and `expandableLayout` before running two loops

Comment: @pskink should i do it in `onViewRecycled` method with `view.removeAllViews`?

Comment: yes, you can do it there as well - maybe its even better place

Comment: @pskink seems like it solves the duplicate problem. but expandable layout height is still way too big for the wrap content (for testing purposes, i've got only 1 visible field and 1 in expandable layout)

Comment: but i would try to reuse them somehow... (to avoid expensive `LayoutInflater#inflate` methods)

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` reuse existing View. When you scroll `RecyclerView` use an existing View to display its item. So clear all views that was previously added  in `visibleLayout`.

```
  viewHolder.visibleLayout.removeAllViews();
   for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : visibleSettings.getVisibleFields().entrySet()) {
    LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.act_row, viewHolder.visibleLayout, false);
    TextView fieldName = row.findViewById(R.id.act_row_field_name);
    TextView fieldValue = row.findViewById(R.id.act_row_field_value);
    fieldName.setText(entry.getKey());
    fieldValue.setText(entry.getValue());
    viewHolder.visibleLayout.addView(row);
}
```

And also remove views from `expandableLayout` before adding.

Comment: If i implement view cleanup in here i've got neither visible layout nor expandable layout, only header is visible and expand button does nothing

Comment: For now, everything seems to work good with `.removeAllViews()` in `onViewRecycled` method, but the height of expandable layout is wrong (see UPD2)

Comment: Try adding `background` color to each layout to see which layout is taking much height

Comment: thx again - done this yesterday but not didn't notice my expandable layout orientation is set to horizontal instead of vertical!